# How to turn off Query creation from method names in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Data is it possible to turn off Query Generation from method names?

Given the interface

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
}
```

I would want spring security to produce an error saying that generating queries from method names has been turned off please use the explicitly @Query annotation like so.

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1 and u.lastname = ?2")
  List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
}
```

I want to turn off the the automatic query generation because I think it is easier to read the query and know what is going on rather than reading the method name and translating to what is the query that Spring data will generate, also on a large team with lots of developers some who might not yet be familiar with spring data @Query is a lot more readable?

How to turn off Query creation from method names in Spring JPA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the `query-lookup-strategy` on the `repositories` tag in the configuration.

```
<repositories query-lookup-strategy="use-declared-query"/>
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-lookup-strategies)

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.findByEmailAddressAndLastName",
    query="select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1 and u.lastname = ?2")
public User{


}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How Spring handles this is called the Query Lookup Strategy. Queries can be resolved by method names (`CREATE`), by manual queries (`USE_DECLARED_QUERY`), or both (`CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND`) which defaults to method names if no manual query is found. USE_DECLARED_QUERY would  give you the desired functionality, warning you if no manual query is specified.

As Kevin answered, this can be configured in xml. But as a more modern option, you can specify the lookup strategy when configuring your repository in a Java Config class with `queryLookupStrategy` parameter in the `@Enable{store}Repositories` annotation.

For example, to force manual queries, you could use the following:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(queryLookupStrategy=QueryLookupStrategy.Key.USE_DECLARED_QUERY)
public class MyDatabaseConfig {
    ...
}
```

More info here

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-lookup-strategies
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryLookupStrategy.Key.html?is-external=true